# IOS Label Animation will not draw inside of label if changing the frame size

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel

Trying to get a basic animation working for moving and downsizing a label.  Animation works fine if the frame size of the label is not changed.  But only draws the border if downsizing the frame.

You can see the commented line, if switched with the line below works fine, as is only the border of the label is drawn.  ToFrame here is smaller than the fromFrame.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:
^{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:fromFrame];
    [label setBackgroundColor:color];
    label.text = text;
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    label.layer.borderWidth = 4;
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

    CGRect frame = label.frame;
    //frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
    frame = toFrame;
    label.frame = frame;
}
completion:^ (BOOL finished)
{
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}

];
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem, i just pasted your code in a test project and it works fine. The only changes i made (clearly) were to text, fromFrame and toFrame

Comment: The problem lies in your commented line. You try to move `origin.y` of label to end of its `superView`. Can you tell me what change you want to apply to label's frame?

Comment: The from frame is something like 10,50,700,100

Comment: The to frame is something like 30,1000,70,50

Comment: The commented line works maybe because the size is not changing, just the y.  The frame=toFrame line is not working maybe because the size is changing?

Comment: Also, the text line is long that fills the label from the start

Comment: Well, this is a moot point now.  Ended up taking an image of the label and then animating the image with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up animating the image of the label / view.  Here is the code, maybe will help someone. Assuming ARC and Quartz include.

```
- (void) animateFromFrame:(CGRect)fromFrame toFrame:(CGRect)toFrame andView:(UIView*)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    imageView.frame = fromFrame;
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 4;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.25 options:nil animations: ^{ imageView.frame = toFrame; } completion:^ (BOOL finished) { [imageView removeFromSuperview]; } ];
}
```